# Checking if a Touch point is inside box collider in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Please see the below images.

[image]

[image]

In the first image you can see that there is box collider.
The second image is when I run the code on Android device

Here is the code which is attached to Play Game (its a 3D Text)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayButton : MonoBehaviour {   

    public string levelToLoad;
    public AudioClip soundhover ;
    public AudioClip beep;
    public bool QuitButton;
    public Transform mButton;
    BoxCollider boxCollider;

    void Start () {
        boxCollider = mButton.collider as  BoxCollider;
    }

    void Update () {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

                if (boxCollider.bounds.Contains (touch.position)) {
                    Application.LoadLevel (levelToLoad);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see if touch point is inside the collider or not. I want to do this because right now if I click any where on the scene 
    Application.LoadLevel(levelToLoad); is called.

I want it to be called if I click on PLAY GAME text only. Can any one help me with this piece of code or can give me another solution to my problem??

---

Recent Code by following Heisenbug's Logic

```
void Update () {

foreach( Touch touch in Input.touches ) {

    if( touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began ) {

        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0));
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 10)) {
            Application.LoadLevel(levelToLoad);             
        }           
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Touch's position is expressed in **screen space coordinate system** (a `Vector2`). You need to convert that position in the **world space coordinate system** before trying to compare it against other 3D locations of objects in the scene.

`Unity3D` provides facility to do that. Since you are using a `BoundingBox` surrounding your text, you can do the following:

- Create a `Ray` which origin is in the touch point position and which direction is parallel to the camera forward axis ([Camera.ScreenPointToRay](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)).
- Check if that ray intersect the `BoundingBox` of your `GameObject` ([Physic.RayCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)).

the code may look something like that:

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0));
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerOfYourGameObject))
{
   //enter here if the object has been hit. The first hit object belongin to the layer "layerOfYourGameObject" is returned.
}
```

It's convenient to add a specific layer to your "Play Game" `GameObject`, in order to make the ray colliding only with it.

---

EDIT

Code and explanation above is fine. If you don't get a proper collision maybe you have not used the right layer. I haven't a touch device at the moment. The following code will work with mouse (without using layers).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestRay : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
            Debug.Log("Mouse pressed " + pos);

            Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray))
            {
                Debug.Log("Something hit");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

It's just an example to put you in the right direction. Try to figure out what's going wrong in your case or post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What I did is that, Selected 3d Text and in the inspector selected assigned layer to it. Layer number was 8. After that I passed the parameter layerOfYourGameObject as 8 and ran the code but still the collision is not occurring. I have attached the code in the Question above.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong on how to add layer to 3D text.
1) Select 3d Text.
2)In Inpector went to AddLayer and named Unity Layer 10 to PlayGameLayer.
3)In inspector Tag = Untagged and Layer = PlayGameLayer.
4) The script with the above code is attached to PlayGame 3d Text.
Is it the right way? If so then what might be wrong?

Comment: @Jawad Amjad: have you attached the bounding box to the same GameObject which has attached Text component?

Comment: Yes I have attached it to 3D Text